# Q&A for Marketing and Advertising (Technology)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-proposal

I would love to see a marketing (product marketing) and advertising section within the Stack Exchange network. Is there a current alternative? Where can I ask and answer questions that are specific to marketing for tech products?

Answer (score 3):

You'd look around on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to see if any new sites have been proposed.

One [Marketing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51786/marketing) didn't gain enough momentum and was closed. As of the time of this answer, a newer [digital marketing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65811/digital-marketing) is in the definition phase, but this eventually didn't make it either. Both proposals have since been deleted.