# Where to ask questions about online advertising

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm interested in learning strategies and tips about online advertising. Especially targeted ads on Facebook, Instagram and Google. I have several questions to ask around this topic.

Where should I ask such questions?

Comment: Related: [Q&A for Marketing and Advertising (Technology)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224713/295232)

Comment: If it is for a website Pro Webmasters might take some specific topics: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but read that on-topic page carefully as well as https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/are-social-media-marketing-questions-on-topic

Answer (score 2):

[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions) sounds like the website you're looking for.  Have a look at the [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) tag there, as well as their [What's on-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, [Are social media marketing questions on-topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/are-social-media-marketing-questions-on-topic), and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badvertising%5D+%22targeted+ads%22) query (a few of those questions also have the [ad-targeting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ad-targeting) tag.)